# Show "n references" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried some extension to Visual Studio 2015 but apparently some of them disable "n references" feature and I want it back!

How can I enable it again?

Comment: Disable the extension? Reset your Visual Studio IDE settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn indicators off or on, except for the references indicator. Go to *Tools, Options, Text Editor, All Languages, CodeLens*.

When the indicators are turned on, you can also open the CodeLens options from the indicators by just right clock in the references count and choose *CodeLens Options*.